# What options do I have for monitoring internet usage by user and sites

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, ubuntu-12.04, bandwidth-measuring

I want to set up a linux server (ubuntu server 12.04) on my home network to monitor the internet usage and find out the users and websites that use the most bandwidth. I have looked at squid and it seems like it might work, are there any other options? ntop also looked good but it doesn't seem like I can filter the results by user (filtering by IP won't work as there are multiple users per computer). I would like a web-based interface to see the results if possible.

Comment: This question can be closed for so many reasons I'm not sure which one to vote for. Please take a moment to read our FAQ.

Comment: Sorry, would this have been a better fit for Super User?

Comment: Yes, it would be a better fit on SU but please read their FAQ before posting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shopping question but; the best solution for this I have found is using Squid as a proxy server, making all users connect to the internet via Squid and then install [Sarg](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/sarg.php) on the squid proxy which you can create daily reports, viewable in a web-based interface, showing you what each IP has viewed, top sites accessed, etc.

Not sure how you could do this via User unless you setup authentication on Squid using some form of AD.

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that, I will probably use proxy authentication on the squid server so hopefully that will work.